# PDO Exception Issue with Binding Placeholder Variables When Using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having an issue with my PDO statement. I am using placeholders / binding in other SQL statements and they all work fine. So I am at a loss as why this one time it doesn't work.

An array gets passed to the function and if the key exists, I append the SQL line with the data.

When I use the placeholder `:categories_slug` I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ':categories_slug INNER JOIN job_types ON jobs.post_type_id =
>   job_types.id WHER' at line 12

The slug variable only contains the letters a through z and the dash (-).

If I replace the line

`$sql .= ' && categories.slug = :categories_slug ';`

With a hard-coded value:

`$sql .= ' && categories.slug = \'business-admin\' ';`

The statement executes just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
$db = static::getDB();

$sql = ' SELECT  students.id, 
                 students.slug, 
                 students.title, 
                 college.name       AS college_name,
                 college.slug       AS college_slug,
                 categories.name    AS categories_name,
                 categories.slug    AS categories_slug,
                 job_types.name     AS job_types_name,
                 job_types.slug     AS job_types_slug 

            FROM students ';

$sql .= ' INNER JOIN college    ON students.college_id  = college.id ';
$sql .= ' INNER JOIN categories ON students.category_id = categories.id ';

if (array_key_exists("categories.slug", $filters) && isset($filters['categories.slug'])) {
//THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE ACCORDING TO THE ERROR
   $sql .= ' && categories.slug = :categories_slug ';
}

$sql .= ' INNER JOIN job_types ON students.post_type_id = job_types.id ';
$sql .= ' WHERE students.deleted_at IS NULL ';


$stmt = $db->query($sql);

if(array_key_exists("categories.slug", $filters) && isset($filters['categories.slug'])){
    $stmt->bindValue( ":categories_slug", $filters['categories.slug'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
}

return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
```

You can't use `query()` when the SQL contains parameter placeholders. You have to use `prepare()` to create the stmt. Then you can bind variables to the parameters, and execute.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(array_key_exists("categories.slug", $filters) && isset($filters['categories.slug'])){
    $stmt->bindValue( ":categories_slug", $filters['categories.slug'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
}
$stmt->execute();
```

The `query()` function is a shortcut that does both prepare & execute, but only when the SQL query contains no parameters.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. That was in my face the whole time. Thank you!